# Mono Gtk#: ButtonPressEvent not work

Tags: c#, events, mono, gtk#

I want to create simple application where I need to add some button press events.. But when I try to add handler to this event to any Widget (except button), it just does not work.

When I click anywhere in window, it does not print nothing. What can I do? I have followed (or tried to follow) this easy tutorial: http://mono-project.com/GtkSharpBeginnersGuide

Here is my code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{   
    public MainWindow (): base (Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        ButtonPressEvent += new ButtonPressEventHandler(ButtonPressHandler);
        ButtonPressEvent += delegate {Console.WriteLine("test 1");};

        SetDefaultSize(50, 50);
        SetPosition(WindowPosition.Center);
        DeleteEvent += new DeleteEventHandler(OnDeleteEvent);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(false, 2);

        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        Menu filemenu = new Menu();
        MenuItem file = new MenuItem("Soubor");
        file.Submenu = filemenu;
        mb.Append(file);

        vbox.PackStart(mb, false, false, 0);

        GuiBoard board = new GuiBoard(3, 3, true);
        board.Board = new Board(5, 7);

        vbox.PackStart(new Entry(), false, false, 0);
        vbox.PackEnd(board, true, true, 0);

        Add(vbox);
        ShowAll();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent (object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit ();
    }

    protected void ButtonPressHandler(object obj, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test!");
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: "not work" tells us very little about the problem you're running into. Compile errors? Runtime exception? What are they? Have you Googled the error to find out what it is and why it's happening? Or is it unexpected behavior? What happened? What did you expect to happen? What have you attempted to fix this already? Please elaborate.

Comment: I wrote: "When I click enywhere in window, it does not print nothing." (sorry for typo). So, there is no compile error, program runs normally without any exceptions. It simply draw GUI but when I click somewhere, nothing is printed, and that is my problem.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that GTK doesn't report events (from mouse or otherwise) by default (except in some widgets like `Gtk.Button`). You can always enable event reporting by setting an appropriate mask for the `Events` property:

```
Events |= Gdk.EventMask.ButtonPressMask | Gdk.EventMask.ButtonReleaseMask;
```

Setting this on the `Window` is enough to have your button press event handler to be called when the user clicks on the window background. If you have other widgets, just set their `Events` property and connect your handler accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
AddEvents((int) (Gdk.EventMask.ButtonPressMask | Gdk.EventMask.ButtonReleaseMask));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Gtk` doesn't get the `ButtonPressEvent` you are using.
For this, you could use `[Glib.ConnectBefore]` to use `ButtonPressEvent`.
That worked for me.

Like:

```
[GLib.ConnectBefore]
protected void ButtonPressHandler(object obj, ButtonPressEventArgs args)
{
   Console.WriteLine("test!");
}
```